# loadHTMLFile fails to return URL

Tags: php, dom, file-io

```
<?php

    $url="http://somedomain/something";
    $lines = file('text.txt');
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url.$line); //cannot load this
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $node) {
    // do stuff with $node
    echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";    



    }
    }   


fclose($handle);

   ?>
```

I would like to attach the url to the lines of the text file:

Example

$url.$line1 (`http://somedomain/something/line1`)

$url.$line2 (`http://somedomain/something/line2`)

I have succesfully set up everything and the loop works well too. But whenever I try to concatenate the url with the line an HTTP 500 Error is returned

Also these characters '%0D%0A' attch themselves to end of the $url.$line and hence the error?

Any help appreciated

Update: The error is because of the '%0D%0A' characters somehow attaching themselves to the end of each url. Any idea how to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra characters you're getting, `%0D%0A`, are the carriage return and line feed characters for Windows computers. To get rid of them, you can use `file` with the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag:

```
$lines = file('text.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

This will stop the carriage return characters being including on the end of each line in the array.

Alternatively, you can chomp the line ending with `rtrim`:

```
$line = rtrim($line);
```